# how to get the output for only the last send in expect scripts

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

I want to use expect_out to get the output for the last send
for the following snippet

```
while {[gets $cmds command]>=0} {
    send "$command\r"
    expect "*"
    set result $expect_out(buffer)
    puts $gout $result
}
```

but expect_out(buffer) seems to maintain all previous outputs
how can I achieve my goal? thanks

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed how much `$expect_out(buffer)` will hold at all, other than that it is _enough_ to match what the `expect` that produced it required to match.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but try adding another `expect *` *before* sending the command.

When in doubt while developing an expect program, add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script.